# prawn font-families update results in empty pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, fonts, prawn

I implemented pdf generation using prawn and this worked on my test server without any problem. 
After deploying and testing the functionality I got the following error message

```
Your document includes text that's not compatible with the Windows-1252 character set.
```

If you need full UTF-8 support, use TTF fonts instead of PDF's built-in fonts.

So I added a TTF font and added this code to the prawn

```
p.font_families.update("DejaVuSerif" => {
       :normal => "#{Rails.root}/path/to/fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf",
 :bold => "#{Rails.root}/path/to/fonts/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf"        
  })

p.font "DejaVuSerif"
```

Now I don't get no error message but it results in empty PDF and there is nothing in error log as well.

anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using prawn with external font

and below is the code in pdf.rb class

```
class DataPDF < Prawn::Document
    def initialize
        font Rails.root.join("app/assets/fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf")
    end
end
```

and make sure the uppercase/lowercase for filename is same with physical file in folder